# Can't access strong Params through another Model. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, associations

For some reason I can't access param from another model. I use in my code `has_many :through` association. I use rails 4.2.

Here is my code:

## /models/company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bonds
  has_many :users, :through => :bonds
end
```

## /models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bonds
  has_many :companies, :through => :bonds
end
```

## /models/bond.rb

```
class Bond < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :companies
  belongs_to :users
end
```

## /config/routes.rb

```
  resources :bonds
  resources :users
  resources :companies
```

I made a simple form where I can made bond between company and user by choosing names and matching them. It works fine. here is code:

## /views/bonds/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@bond) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.select :users_id, User.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.select :companies_id, Company.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

## Here is code that stops working: /views/bonds/show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @bond.users.name %> 
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Company:</strong>
  <%= @bond.companies.name %>
</p>
```

It shows this error:

> uninitialized constant Bond::Users

But if i change `/views/bonds/show.html.erb` to this it works fine.

```
<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @bond.users_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Company:</strong>
  <%= @bond.companies_id %>
</p>
```

Maybe someone can help? i think it might be because i can't access `strong params` from other models. But i don't know how to solve it.

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see a user name, to which `@bond` is associated you would:

1) change `belongs_to :bonds` to `belongs_to :bond` (note it's singular  for `belongs_to` type of association);

2) rename `users_id` column in `bonds` table to `user_id`;

2) write `@bond.user.name`.

Comment: how could I call for `users.name` through `bond` if they are associated?

Comment: @DanielsV you can only call a `name` on an instance, not on a collection. To see all `@bond.users` names you would do `@bond.users.pluck(:name)` (same as `@bond.users.map(&:name)`)

Comment: i only need to see one users name. The one bond is associated with. Maybe you can tell how can i do it?

Comment: Sound like you are right :D now i have this one `undefined method 'name'` maybe you have solution for this one too?

Comment: @DanielsV check out to make sure you've changed plural to singular **every**where needed (in forms, for instance - `f.select :users_id` => `f.select :user_id`). To check what's wrong with `name` check if your `users` table in db has a `name` column. Checkout your migrations and primary keys in db.

Comment: @DanielsV later, when you resolve the issue (and find out many more) consider marking the answer as accepted (if that helped). Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78472/discussion-between-danielsv-and-andrey-deineko).